# How to copy properties file first and then load them in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am writing a build script where I want to first copy a test.properties file to a directory build/spec/ and load those using Properties.
Here is my code bellow:

```
Properties props = new Properties()

task resourceCopy(type:Copy){
  from resourceDir
  into "build"
}

task loadProp(dependsOn:resourceCop){
  props.load(new FileInputStream("build/spec/test.properties"))
}
```

But this is always giving error as:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ultra-core-rpm'.
```

> build/spec/test.properties (No such file or directory)

Please suggest how to first copy and then load properties file at runtime?

Comment: Basically, I am downloading the properties file from git and loading them in variables in build.gradle. Now for that every other task which is using those variables need to be performed inside a doLast{} section. Is it a correct way to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
task loadProp(dependsOn:resourceCop){
  props.load(new FileInputStream("build/spec/test.properties"))
}
```

should be

```
task loadProp(dependsOn:resourceCopy) {
  doLast {
    props.load(new FileInputStream("build/spec/test.properties"))
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you're not loading the properties when the task is *executed*, but when the task is *configured*.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But while accessing props.getProperty("key"), it is throwing NullPointerException

Comment: Can't say without seeing the code and the stacktrace.